# Use Darknet with zmq and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, zeromq, darknet

guys, I'm having a really bad time trying to encapsulate my neural network to scan images streamed from a remote raspberry pi to my processing server. I've managed to create a client that sends Raspberry Pi Camera's images over [imagezmq](https://pypi.org/project/imagezmq/) library and as of now I am trying to get my stream to pass through [Yolov4](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet) network, as i have everything set up in server side.

My only problem is getting the zeromq stream and put it inside cv2.VideoCapture Function.
I've followed [this guide](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/04/15/live-video-streaming-over-network-with-opencv-and-imagezmq/) and i am trying to process my stream with [this video code example](https://github.com/yiningzeng/darknet-fork-from-AlexeyAB/blob/dev/darknet_video.py) but i have no success...

I am desperated.

Client Code (Raspberry)

```
import imagezmq
import argparse
import socket
import time

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-s", "--server-ip", required=True,
    help="ip address of the server to which the client will connect")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# initialize the ImageSender object with the socket address of the
# server
sender = imagezmq.ImageSender(connect_to="tcp://{}:5555".format(
    args["server_ip"]))


# get the host name, initialize the video stream, and allow the
# camera sensor to warmup
rpiName = socket.gethostname()
vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True, resolution=(800, 600)).start()
time.sleep(2.0)
 
while True:
    # read the frame from the camera and send it to the server
    frame = vs.read()
    sender.send_image(rpiName, frame)
```

Server Code (main PC)

```
import random
import os
import cv2
import time
import darknet
import argparse
from threading import Thread, enumerate
from queue import Queue
import imagezmq





# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments

# initialize the ImageHub object
imageHub = imagezmq.ImageHub()
# initialize the list of class labels MobileNet SSD was trained to
# detect, then generate a set of bounding box colors for each class
# load our serialized model from disk
print("[INFO] loading model...")


def parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="YOLO Object Detection")
    parser.add_argument("--input", type=str, default=0,
                        help="video source. If empty, uses webcam 0 stream")
    parser.add_argument("--out_filename", type=str, default="",
                        help="inference video name. Not saved if empty")
    parser.add_argument("--weights", default="yolov4.weights",
                        help="yolo weights path")
    parser.add_argument("--dont_show", action='store_true',
                        help="windown inference display. For headless systems")
    parser.add_argument("--ext_output", action='store_true',
                        help="display bbox coordinates of detected objects")
    parser.add_argument("--config_file", default="./cfg/yolov4.cfg",
                        help="path to config file")
    parser.add_argument("--data_file", default="./cfg/coco.data",
                        help="path to data file")
    parser.add_argument("--thresh", type=float, default=.25,
                        help="remove detections with confidence below this value")
    return parser.parse_args()


def str2int(video_path):
    """
    argparse returns and string althout webcam uses int (0, 1 ...)
    Cast to int if needed
    """
    try:
        return int(video_path)
    except ValueError:
        return video_path

path_cfg = "cfg/coco.data"
detector_cfg = "backup/custom-yolov4-detector.cfg"
detector_weights = "backup/custom-yolov4-detector_best.weights"

def check_arguments_errors(args):
    assert 0 < args.thresh < 1, "Threshold should be a float between zero and one (non-inclusive)"
    if not os.path.exists(detector_cfg):
        raise(ValueError("Invalid config path {}".format(os.path.abspath(args.config_file))))
    if not os.path.exists(detector_weights):
        raise(ValueError("Invalid weight path {}".format(os.path.abspath(args.weights))))
    if not os.path.exists(path_cfg):
        raise(ValueError("Invalid data file path {}".format(os.path.abspath(args.data_file))))
    if str2int(args.input) == str and not os.path.exists(args.input):
        raise(ValueError("Invalid video path {}".format(os.path.abspath(args.input))))


def set_saved_video(input_video, output_video, size):
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
    fps = int(input_video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
    video = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video, fourcc, fps, size)
    return video


def video_capture(frame_queue, darknet_image_queue):
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret,frame = imageHub.recv_image()
        imageHub.send_reply(b'OK')
        if not ret:
            break
        frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame_rgb, (width, height),
                                   interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        frame_queue.put(frame_resized)
        darknet.copy_image_from_bytes(darknet_image, frame_resized.tobytes())
        darknet_image_queue.put(darknet_image)
    cap.release()


def inference(darknet_image_queue, detections_queue, fps_queue):
    while cap.isOpened():
        darknet_image = darknet_image_queue.get()
        prev_time = time.time()
        detections = darknet.detect_image(network, class_names, darknet_image, thresh=args.thresh)
        detections_queue.put(detections)
        fps = int(1/(time.time() - prev_time))
        fps_queue.put(fps)
        print("FPS: {}".format(fps))
        darknet.print_detections(detections, args.ext_output)
        darknet.free_image(darknet_image)
    cap.release()


def drawing(frame_queue, detections_queue, fps_queue):
    random.seed(3)  # deterministic bbox colors
    video = set_saved_video(cap, args.out_filename, (width, height))
    while cap.isOpened():
        frame_resized = frame_queue.get()
        detections = detections_queue.get()
        fps = fps_queue.get()
        if frame_resized is not None:
            image = darknet.draw_boxes(detections, frame_resized, class_colors)
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            if args.out_filename is not None:
                video.write(image)
            if not args.dont_show:
                cv2.imshow('Inference', image)
            if cv2.waitKey(fps) == 27:
                break
    cap.release()
    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    frame_queue = Queue()
    darknet_image_queue = Queue(maxsize=1)
    detections_queue = Queue(maxsize=1)
    fps_queue = Queue(maxsize=1)

    args = parser()
    check_arguments_errors(args)
    network, class_names, class_colors = darknet.load_network(
            args.config_file,
            args.data_file,
            args.weights,
            batch_size=1
        )
    # Darknet doesn't accept numpy images.
    # Create one with image we reuse for each detect
    width = darknet.network_width(network)
    height = darknet.network_height(network)
    darknet_image = darknet.make_image(width, height, 3)
    frame = imageHub.recv_image()
    cap = cv2.imdecode("Output Frame", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    Thread(target=video_capture, args=(frame_queue, darknet_image_queue)).start()
    Thread(target=inference, args=(darknet_image_queue, detections_queue, fps_queue)).start()
 Thread(target=drawing, args=(frame_queue, detections_queue, fps_queue)).start()
```

Comment: but you don't use `cv.VideoCapture` at all? you shouldn't use it. OpenCV is not a media library, it intentionally doesn't give you the flexibility you need. give PyAV a look.

Comment: Thank you @ChristophRackwitz! I will give a look on that. I've tweaked the code a little bit now, and I removed all cv2 checkings, but still having problems on dealing with threads, i guess i will have to change the way i pass my zmq frames into the Darknet... anyway, thank you for your tip!

Comment: do you have any solution for this @CaioVC, I'm struggling with the same problem now. I need to use cv2.grab() and cv2.retrieve() but it's useless since I transport the image using imagezmq so I don't have cap (cv2.VideoCapture). What's your approach in here (using opencv dnn require it to run in cuda to get best fps while threaded can get almost as good as cuda in CPU)